# PHPExcel cells merge set font smaller to fit into the merged cells with fixed width and height

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using **PHPExcel** to generate an Excel file for an order.

I have some ***constraints***:

- cells are merged
- cell are aligned vertical and horizontal to center
- text is wrapped and on multiple lines
- text need to fit the merge cells: ***if too long*** to fit ***set font smaller*** but keep the text wrap

I have done the first 3 but I can't achieve the last requirement.

Example of:

what I have

[image]

what I need

[image]

The **rows and columns are standard** width and height and **can't be changed** due to the other cells width and height. Client design....

I have tried:

```
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A28:C32');      
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A28')->getAlignment()->applyFromArray(
        array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical'   => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
            'rotation'   => 0,
            'wrap'       => true
        )
    )->setShrinkToFit(true);
```

and any other combination of these above:

```
            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A28:C32');
            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A28:C32')->getAlignment()->applyFromArray(
        array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical'   => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
            'rotation'   => 0,
            'wrap'       => true
        )
     )->setShrinkToFit(true);

             //or this
             $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A28:C32')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true)->setShrinkToFit(true);
```

I'm aware of

```
             $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setSize(10);
```

but ***I need the text to be smaller only if it is not fit the merged cells***.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to actually **count the number of lines** and set the font accordingly.

If the **number of lines of string is greater** *than* **number of rows of merged cells** (5 in my case) then set the font smaller.

```
  if (substr_count($return_to, "\n") <= 4){ //count 5 lines or less -> font = 10

      $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A28")->getFont()->setSize(10);

  }else{ //count more than 5 lines -> font = 9

      $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A28")->getFont()->setSize(9);

  }
```